# Isolated scope for individual items in list in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a list of items which I'm populating using ng-repeat

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="setClass" ng-click="assignClass()">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

and in my controller

```
$scope.assignClass = function(){
    $scope.setClass = "sampleClass";
}
```

When I'm doing like this and clicking on any one item all the items are getting the **sampleClass** added.

I need this scenario,

When I click on the first item that item should have the **sampleClass** and when I click on the second item I want both first and second items should have **sampleClass**

How can I achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you we're using sets the styling for all the list items as you mentioned.
I've change the code a bit to set the class for an individual item in the unordered list.
By calling the assignClass using the selected item as a parameter you can set the class for this item.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="item.setClass" ng-click="assignClass(item)">
        {{item.name}}
    </li>
</ul> 


$scope.assignClass = function(selectedItem){
    selectedItem.setClass = "sampleClass";
}
```

Comment: Maybe a little bit information about why this change fixes his issue would improve the answer :)

Comment: Yeah you are probably right :) added some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `item` into `assignClass` function.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="assignClass(item)">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Then change the class of that item

```
$scope.assignClass = function(item){
    $(item).toggleClass("sampleClass");
}
```